# How to upgrade Liferay 6.2 portlet to Liferay 7.2

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-7

Are there tools to upgrade liferay version 6.2 to Liferay version 7.2?

I have a project with Liferay 6.2 (theme and portlet),I have followed the documentation of Upgrading Code of Liferay Portal CE 7.2, starting with theme upgrade but there are some things that are not working for me :

```
yo liferay-theme:import
```

> Error liferay-theme:import You don't seem to have a generator with the
>   name “liferay-theme:import” installed.

Script 6.2 groovy

> startup failed: Script1.groovy: 15: unable to resolve class
>   com.liferay.portal.model.Group

Can anyone offer advice on how I can upgrade my project (theme , portlet)?

Comment: The question says you want to upgrade a portlet. The examples you show suggest you want to upgrade a theme. So which one it is? Can you please update the question stating what is it that you now have and what have you tried?

Comment: You do have a whole documentation available: https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-0/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/upgrading-plugins-to-liferay-7 looks at the 7.0 doc to have more info about coming from 6.x version.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest dividing the problem into three sub-problems

First the portlet conversion requires an update of the code
so the code is stored in the database so you have to perform Mysql upgrades...

Next you need to upgrade the Models (So core liferay will be Upgraded)
se link -- [upgrade liferay](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029316391-Introduction-to-Upgrading-Code-to-Liferay-DXP-7-2)

Third I will upgrade Theme, I would like to mention that in liferay 7.2 Velocity is no longer used, In this case Freemarker is used
we follow the link for theme upgrade [theme upgrade](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029316931-Upgrading-6-2-Layout-Templates-to-7-2)

Best Regards!